# When recycleview scrolling parent activity button go disable

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView grid adapter contains checkboxes and a show button in parent activity.if we select checkbox parent activity show button to enable and if we unchecked checkbox show button will disable, this how my requirement, and its working fine, but when I scroll recycle view my show button to disable. When I scroll I am getting `item.isChecked()` is false..can anyone help me to achieve my requirement, pls explain

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    try {
        final GridViewHolder viewHolder = (GridViewHolder) holder;

        final MyList item = items.get(position);

        viewHolder.myCheckBox.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.myCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
   CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, 
    boolean b) {

                item.setChecked(b);

                if (item.isChecked())
                   Count++;
                else
                  Count--;

                if (Count > 0) {

                    ((MyActivity)context).showButton().setEnabled(true);

                } else {
                    ((MyActivity)context).showButton().setEnabled(false);
                }


        }
        });

        viewHolder.myCheckBox.setChecked(item.isChecked());


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In my pojo list class i written two functions for identy checkbox return values

```
  boolean isChecked;
  public boolean isChecked() {
    return isChecked;
  }

public void setChecked(boolean isChecked) {
    this.isChecked = isChecked;
}
```

ViewHolder inner class in adapter

```
   public class GridViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    private CheckBox myCheckBox;


     public GridViewHolder(final View parent) {
        super(parent);

        myCheckBox = (CheckBox) parent.findViewById(myCheckBox);

       ((ProductListingActivity)context).showButton().setEnabled(false);

        parent.setOnClickListener(GridAdapterMy.this);
    }
  }
```

Comment: as i told you need to save state of check box my friend

Comment: pls can u just post me any code example ,pls see my code

Comment: wait i wll share you a code

Comment: dear friend seriusly am not getting any idea,am a beginer,where i have to place dis code?in onbindviewholder or ViewHolder?actually am using pagination in main activity,so each time recyclerview scroll api call happen and adding new data to list.and my checkbox status is still stable,only show button status changing

Comment: see my answer remove setOnCheckedChangeListener and used setOnClickListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue as yours and this is how I fixed it.

```
@Override 
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    try {
        final GridViewHolder viewHolder = (GridViewHolder) holder;

        viewHolder.myCheckBox.setTag(position);

        //add this two lines 
        viewHolder.myCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        viewHolder.myCheckBox.setChecked(items.get(position).isChecked());

        viewHolder.myCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
            CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton,boolean b) {


                items.get(position).setChecked(b);

                if (items.get(position).isChecked())
                   Count++;
                else
                  Count--;

                if (Count > 0) {
                   ((MyActivity)context).showButton().setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                   ((MyActivity)context).showButton().setEnabled(false);
                }}
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u,but its not working in my case

Comment: have put this `viewHolder.myCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        viewHolder.myCheckBox.setChecked(item.isChecked());`
before assigning listener to your view?

Comment: when i scroll down again button visibility go disable.

Comment: just do 1 thing copy `onBindViewHolder()` from above posted ans

Comment: @user8737536 I have updated my answer, try it again.

Comment: ok let me try,need to change anything on pojo class?

Comment: No, you were storing check item data in the local object, that's why your original data was not reflecting over the original ArrayList.

Comment: pls check my view holder class,intially there am setting showbutton disable,any problem?

Comment: i implimeted ur code,but still facing same problem..i think am getting item checked() is fals every time am scrolling

Comment: Your ViewHolder class looks ok, it seems you are doing something wrong because above solution is working in many of my cases

Comment: am getting list through pagination,everytime scroll recyclyview its calling api,dnt noe where i miss the part

Comment: come to chat room and share your code over there

Comment: i dnt have much reputation for chat-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159581/discussion-between-maddy-and-user8737536).

Answer (score 1):

While scrolling  `onBindViewHolder` called repetitively that's why state of checkbox changed automatically.so you have to save state of checkbox while scroll. 
have look.

```
    public class MyListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

       private final boolean[] mCheckedState;
       private final Context mContext;
       private CheckBox result;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<Object> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        mCheckedState = new boolean[objects.size()];
        mContext = context;
    }

  @Override 
 public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
   try {
    final GridViewHolder viewHolder = (GridViewHolder) holder;
    viewHolder.myCheckBox.setTag(position);

    //add this two lines 
    viewHolder.myCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);       
    result =  viewHolder.myCheckBox;
    if (result == null) {
        result = new CheckBox(mContext);
    }
    result.setChecked(mCheckedState[position]);
    viewHolder.myCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
        CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton,boolean b) {

             if(b){
                result.setChecked(mCheckedState[position]);
                  }
    });

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}
    }

Happy coding!!

Comment: thank u,let me try

Comment: hai here vat is "CheckBox result = (CheckBox)convertView;" ,what is convertview?

Comment: i update the code. please try it.

Comment: cannot return a value with method void return type,i put ur code inside onbind ,its void method

Comment: can u pls update in my code?

Comment: yes i update your code, try this.

Comment: i updated ur code,but when i scroll selected checkbox also unchecked..and where i have to put my showbutton,pls check my code..

Answer (score 1):

Create an extra variable in your **POJO class**:

```
public class DataItems {   

    int id, price, qty;
    String title;

    boolean isChecked; // create boolean variable like this

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        isChecked = checked;
    }

}
```

then, add code like this in your adapter:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        // check here the state of your check from your arraylist of POJO
        if (dataItemsArrayList.get(position).isChecked) {
            holder.chkBox.setChecked(true);               
        } else {
            holder.chkBox.setChecked(false);
        }

        holder.tvTitle.setText(dataItemsArrayList.get(position).getTitle() + "");
        holder.tvPrice.setText(dataItemsArrayList.get(position).getPrice() + "");
        holder.tvQTY.setText(dataItemsArrayList.get(position).getQty() + "");
        holder.chkBox.setTag(position);

        holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // save here the state of your check box when your select or unSelect the Checkbox
                if (isChecked) {

                    ((MainActivity)context).isChecked(true);
                    holder.chkBox.setChecked(true);
                    dataItemsArrayList.get(position).setChecked(true);


                } else {
                    ((MainActivity)context).isChecked(false);
                    holder.chkBox.setChecked(false);
                    dataItemsArrayList.get(position).setChecked(false);
                }

            }
        });

}
```

**EDIT**

Create a new `Interface` like below

```
public interface test {

    public void isChecked(boolean isChecked);
}
```

now implements in Your Activity like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements test
```

than pass this Activity Context as parameter to Your Adapter

than add this code in Your activity

```
 @Override
    public void isChecked(boolean isChecked) {

        if(isChecked){
            // enable YOur Button here
        }else {
            // disable YOur Button here
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank u,let me try

Comment: welcome @user8737536 let me know if any query

Comment: actually in my code am able keep checkbox status,problem with my showbutton..pls ready my question

Comment: as told you earlier use interface

Comment: @user8737536 check updated ans my Friend

Comment: ok thank u,will try

Comment: @user8737536 let me know if any query

Comment: hai i cant add this line " ((MainActivity)context).isChecked(false); " in my code,actually i am calling parent button in adapter,my code is  ((MyActivity)context).showButton().setEnabled(true);

Comment: @user8737536 did you **implements test** interface in your activity

Comment: yes implemented

Comment: did you pass your Activity context as a parameter in Adapter

Comment: my interface is calling,but when i do scroll getting  item checked as false,and everytinme view holder calling,checkmy viewholder clsass,there i set showbutton visibility disable for intitial call

Comment: @user8737536 can you share your code with me

Answer (score 1):

try with this code

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    try {
        final GridViewHolder viewHolder = (GridViewHolder) holder;

        final MyList item = items.get(position);

        viewHolder.myCheckBox.setTag(position);

        //add this two lines 
//        viewHolder.myCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        viewHolder.myCheckBox.setChecked(item.isChecked());
        viewHolder.myCheckBox.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.myCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString().trim());

                items.get(pos).setChecked(b);
                if(items.get(pos).isChecked()){
                    items.get(pos).setChecked(false);
                }else{
                    items.get(pos).setChecked(true);
                }

                if (items.get(pos).isChecked())
                   Count++;
                else
                  Count--;

                if (Count > 0) {
                   ((MyActivity)context).showButton().setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                   ((MyActivity)context).showButton().setEnabled(false);
                }
                });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who helped me,i found my mistake,each time when i scroll,my setOnCheckedChangeListener was calling,thats why my button go disable,i added just one line "viewHolder.myCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);" its working perfectly..thank u somuch for urs advice and help